# importing a class from another package - Python

Tags: python

My directory structure is like this:

```
app/
-sub1/
  -sub1_1/
  -sub1_2/
  -sub1_3/
-sub2
 -class1.py
-app.py
```

I am running a flask app which is trying to execute app.py from the app folder.
I want to import the classes from files inside sub1 in class files inside sub2.

I want to do this without setting **sys.path**

Update: I have _ *init* _.py in all folder levels

Comment: `from .. import App`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `app.py`, the `app` directory is your module root, you could just use

```
from sub2 import class1
```

There is also relative imports:

```
from ..sub2 import class
```

for modules located in sub2/sub2_N it'll be `from ...sub2`.

Note: relative imports won't work in Python 2.6 and 2.7 (2.5- do not have this) unless you add this line to the top of file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_imports
```

Comment: This is wrong. You need `from sub1.sub1_1 import class1` instead. With your code you trying to import the _module_ `class1` from the package `sub2` not the class `class1`.

Comment: @ChristianDean How should I do the import of class1 inside sub1.sub1_1 in a file inside sub2

Comment: @Sriram You would need to do from `.sub1 import * `... but you need to have an `__init__.py` file inside `sub1` or else it won't be considered a valid submodule.

Comment: the `__init__.py` doesn't need to have anything it in, it just needs to be there.

Comment: @CoolqB Actually, in Python 3 you are no longer required to create an `__init__.py` file for Python to recognize a folder as a package. OTHO, you may want to add one anyway for Python 2 compatibility.